# Rotating circle at the bottom of screen

Tags: android, rotation

I have been using this tutorial to make a rotating view:-
[Rotating Dialler](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868)

Here is the code for it:-

```
private static Bitmap imageOriginal, imageScaled;
private static Matrix matrix;

private ImageView dialer;
private int dialerHeight, dialerWidth;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (imageOriginal == null) {
        imageOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dialler);
    }

    // initialize the matrix only once
    if (matrix == null) {
        matrix = new Matrix();
    } else {
        // not needed, you can also post the matrix immediately to restore the old state
        matrix.reset();
    }


    dialer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_ring);
    dialer.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());
    dialer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // method called more than once, but the values only need to be initialized one time
            if (dialerHeight == 0 || dialerWidth == 0) {
                dialerHeight = dialer.getHeight();
                dialerWidth = dialer.getWidth();

                // resize
                Matrix resize = new Matrix();
                resize.postScale((float)Math.min(dialerWidth, dialerHeight) / (float)imageOriginal.getWidth(), (float)Math.min(dialerWidth, dialerHeight) / (float)imageOriginal.getHeight());
                imageScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.getWidth(), imageOriginal.getHeight(), resize, false);

                // translate to the image view's center
                float translateX = dialerWidth / 2 - imageScaled.getWidth() / 2;
                float translateY = dialerHeight / 2 - imageScaled.getHeight() / 2;
                matrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);

                dialer.setImageBitmap(imageScaled);
                dialer.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
        }
    });
}

private class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private double startAngle;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                rotateDialer((float) (startAngle - currentAngle));
                startAngle = currentAngle;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

}

private double getAngle(double xTouch, double yTouch) {
    double x = xTouch - (dialerWidth / 2d);
    double y = dialerHeight - yTouch - (dialerHeight / 2d);

    switch (getQuadrant(x, y)) {
        case 1:
            return Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        case 2:
            return 180 - Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        case 3:
            return 180 + (-1 * Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI);
        case 4:
            return 360 + Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * @return The selected quadrant.
 */
private static int getQuadrant(double x, double y) {
    if (x >= 0) {
        return y >= 0 ? 1 : 4;
    } else {
        return y >= 0 ? 2 : 3;
    }
}

private void rotateDialer(float degrees) {
    matrix.postRotate(degrees, dialerWidth / 2, dialerHeight / 2);

    dialer.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

This works fine when the image is center. What i need is the image to be at bottom of screen and as a semicircle (Half of the circle would be outside of the screen below). Some thing like this:-
[image]

It needs to be rotating on user touch.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your ImageView in a RelativeLayout, align it to the bottom and then set layout_marginBottom as a negative value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/graphic_ring"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_ring"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```